# Can't get right value for element id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of the id attribute of an element.

javascript:

```
function checkPhoneZip() {
$.get(encodeURI("checkPhoneZip.aspx?mobilePhone=" + $("#mobilePhone").val() + "&postalCode=" + $("#postalCode").val()), function (data) {
    $("#ajaxResults").html(data);
})
    .done(function () {

        var divs = $("#ajaxResults").find('div');
        if (divs.length == 1) {
            if ($("#ajaxResults").html() == "<div>dbEmpty<div>") {
                $("#emailGetError").text("Cannot find an email address for the information entered");
            }
            else {
                $("#user").val($("#ajaxResults").text())
                $("#user").focus();
                $("#emailRecovery").slideUp();
            }                
        }
        else {
            var options = "";
            for (i = 0; 1 < divs.length; i++) {
                options += "<option value='" + $(divs[i]).attr("id") + "'>" + $(divs[i]).text() + "</option>";
            }
            $("#companies").html("<option selected>Select which business you are</option>" + options);
            $("#companies").slideDown('fast');
        }
    })
    .fail(function () { alert("Failed to contact Database. Please try again in a few seconds"); })
;
```

}

html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="passwordReset.aspx.cs" Inherits="passwordReset" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <style type="text/css">
        .link{text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer}
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="getCode" runat="server">
            <div>Enter the email address associated with your account and a verification code will be texted to the mobile phone number you used to sign up.</div>
            <div>
                <input id="user" runat="server" type="email" />
                <div id="userError"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="getCodeButton">GET CODE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="link" id="forgotEmail">Forgot email address?</div>
        </div>
        <div id="emailRecovery" style="display:none">
            <div>Enter the mobile phone number you registered with</div>
            <div><input type="tel" id="mobilePhone" /></div>
            <div>Enter the postal code you registered with</div>
            <div><input type="text" id="postalCode" /></div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="getEmailButton">GET EMAIL</button>
            </div>
            <div id="emailGetError"></div>
            <div id="chooseCompany" style="display:none">
                <select id="companies"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="code" runat="server" style="display:none">
            <div>A text message with a verification code has been sent to <span id="msgPhone"></span>.<br />Enter the code you received below.</div>
            <div><input type="text" id="codeInput" /></div>
            <div id="codeInputError"></div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="sendCodeButton">SEND CODE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="changePass" style="display:none">
            <div>Enter new password</div>
            <div><input type="text" id="pwInput1" /></div>
            <div id="pwInput1Error"></div>
            <div>Enter new password again</div>
            <div><input type="text" id="pwInput2" /></div>
            <div id="pwInput2Error"></div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="changePassButton">UPDATE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id ="ajaxResults" style="display:none"></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="passwordReset.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This part, $(divs[i]).attr("id"), comes back as undefined in the debugger. I'm trying to get the value of the id attribute of each div inside of #ajaxResults, and each div does have an id attribute. Something wrong with my syntax or understanding.

Comment: Instead of doing $(element[i]) use element.eq(i) instead to not breakout of the jquery object forcing the rewrap.  Not saying that will fix your issue, but it reduces the work your doing.

Comment: Or, just do divs[i].id without using jQuery at all.

Comment: Is there something that is populating #ajaxResults?

Comment: I don't understand why $(divs[i]).text() does give the correct value but $(divs[i]).attr("id") does not. Seems like the syntax is the same on both.

Comment: provide enough html to reproduce this. Are there nested `<div>` that don't have id?

Comment: Post here what divs actually has to answer it?

Comment: ajaxResults is getter populated by the ajax callback data. It has exactly what I expect in there before I use it in my code above.

Comment: You can do `console.log(divs.eq(i).prop('outerHTML'))` to see exactly what they are.

Comment: I thought I posted enough. Let me edit it.

Comment: should be sufficient enough code now.

Comment: note you are using 2 `done()` methods ...the callback of `$.get()` and `done()` fire at same time ... combine them since it's hard to know which will complete first

Comment: your $("#ajaxResults").find('div') gives you 0 divs contained in your HTML so all the remaining code is not executed and at the end you add only an empty select.

Comment: ------"your $("#ajaxResults").find('div') gives you 0 divs contained in your HTML so all the remaining code is not executed and at the end you add only an empty select"

Comment: options += "<option value='" + $(divs[i]).attr("id") + "'>" + $(divs[i]).text() + "</option>";   $(divs[i]).text() returns a value.   $(divs[i]).attr("id") is undefined. I definiotely have divs in the ajaxResults as I can see them.

Comment: $(divs[i]).text() returns a value.         $(divs[i]).attr("id") is undefined

Comment: You have shown us everything except the elements you are trying to get id from. Create demo that reproduces issue

Comment: I found the problem. Should I post it or just delete the question?

Comment: delete it...nothing but noise here

Comment: well thanks alot for the attitude. I'll delete it. Sorry to bother you

Comment: @user192632 don't take it personally bro...good thing you found your mistake by yourself. If you feel the need to post your answer, go ahead and post it. Don't ask, just do it. If it the question is already been asked or gets a lot of downvotes it will be closed for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're biggest problem is your `for` loop is checking `1 < divs.length` instead of `i < divs.length`.

Use this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    options += "<option value='" + $(divs[i]).attr("id") + "'>" + $(divs[i]).text() + "</option>";
}
```

Comment: divs is the name of the array that stores the results of the divs I find within #ajaxResults. div is not an array.